# On crossed product of L^{P} spaces

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra with faithful normal state $\varphi$, and $G$ be a group action on $M$ preserving $\varphi$. Then is it true 
\begin{align*}
L^{p}(M\rtimes G, \varphi^{M\rtimes G})\cong L^{p}(M,\varphi)\rtimes G?
\end{align*}

Comment: The right hand side of the isomorphism doesn't make sense to me a priori. I assume the crossed product of the left is the spatial crossed product of von Neumann algebras, but how do you define the crossed product on the right? $L^p$ is not a von Neumann algebra.

Comment: Btw, there is a notion of crossed products for operator systems (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.10759.pdf), but it is recent and is not clear to me if that is what you are using.

Comment: @Adrian right side is about crossed product of the operator systems

Comment: Then, I may advise you to explain a little bit the definition you are working with and what have you tried (isn't embedding $\mathbf{C} G$ inside $L^p(M) \rtimes G$ and taking closures enough to disprove your identity?)